# Rspec: Why isn't my model valid in general?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec-rails

The issue has to do with my factories but I'll show my **location_spec.rb** first:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Location do

  before(:each) do
    @location = FactoryGirl.build(:location)
  end

  subject { @location }

  describe "should be valid in general" do
    it { should be_valid }
  end

  describe "when user_id is not present" do
    before { @location.user_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when owner_id is not present" do
    before { @location.owner_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

Here is my **factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username   'user1'
    email      'user@example.com'
    timezone   'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
    password   'testing'
  end

  factory :owner do
    name    'Owner One'
    user
  end

  factory :location do
    name 'Location One'
    about 'About this location'
    website 'http://www.locationone.com/'
    phone_number '12 323-4234'
    street_address 'Shibuya, Tokyo, Japan'


    association :owner, strategy: :build
  end
end
```

**Location.rb**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :about, :name, :owner_id, :phone_number,:street_address, :website
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :owner_id
  validates_presence_of :user_id
end
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Failures:

  1) Location should be valid in general
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected valid? to return true, got false
    #./spec/models/location_spec.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I get this error because I'm building the associations incorrectly for Location I believe. The associations should be the user and owner are already saved and than just have the location already assigned to both. Am I on the right track  with my factories or is it something else? What do you think?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, I am not an expert but is this correct? `association :owner, strategy: :build` ? or should it be `association :owner, strategy :build`?

Comment: @Kiran I'm just going by what the guide said: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations. Or at least trying to.

Comment: Might help if you included your validations in the Location model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strategy: :build` option is telling FactoryGirl not to actually save the associated model (owner) for both `FactoryGirl.create` and `FactoryGirl.build`. I don't think this is what you want.

Try changing the factory line with the owner to just `owner`, like this:

```
factory :location do
  name 'Location One'
  about 'About this location'
  website 'http://www.locationone.com/'
  phone_number '12 323-4234'
  street_address 'Shibuya, Tokyo, Japan'

  owner
end
```

What that will do is to create the association before instantiating the location record, so that the location will be valid. If you don't do this, then validation on the parent (location) will fail because there will be no `owner_id` to assign (the owner will not have been created yet).

**UPDATE**:

It looks like you're also missing the `user` association in your `location` factory, which it also validates. So add that to your factory as well to get it to pass:

```
factory :location do
  name 'Location One'
  about 'About this location'
  website 'http://www.locationone.com/'
  phone_number '12 323-4234'
  street_address 'Shibuya, Tokyo, Japan'

  owner
  user
end
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: The same thing still happened. By the way does this also secure my association for the `User`?

Comment: Oh probably because you're missing the user, which location also validates. Try adding a `user` under `owner` in the factory.

Comment: I did this before and when I do it the `User` tries to be created twice from the `Owner` creation but it can't of course since the email and username are already taken. I don't know how I would assign the `Owner` and `Location` with `User` without getting rid of the `user` inside of the `Owner` factory.

Comment: You should use a sequence for the email in your user factory, that will avoid uniqueness issues. There's info in the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage), but basically you create the sequence with `sequence :email { |n| "user#{n}@example.com" }` and then in the factory just leave the email as `email`, with no email address value (factorygirl will automatically create it using the sequence.

Comment: Oh ok now I understand what's going on. The owner and location have the same user but the Owner in the other block had the same user too.  Thanks again.